# Laravel - Cambio de formato de fechas

Tags: laravel

estoy teniendo un inconveniente algo extraño, tenia mi web montada en un servidor con DirectAdmin, todo funcionando OK, y por alguna razon el dueño del servidor debio restaurar la instancia por un problema que tuve, obviamente colocando un backup, etc...

El problema es que se cambio el formato de todas las fechas. Por ejemplo anteriormente las fechas me las leia asi "2019/06/11" y ahora las lee así "jun 20 2019 12:00:00:".
Investigando un poco en el código y utilizando la funcion dd(); para que imprima lo que necesito, noto que es como si directamente de la base de datos me devolviera el valor asi, pero en la base de datos la columna es datetime con primer formato escrito arriba.

Intente utilizar Carbon \Carbon\Carbon::parse($variable)->format('y M d'); pero me dice que la funcion format() no existe.

Cual podria ser la solucion para poder ver la fecha en el formato "yyyy/MM/dd"?

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría poniendo en la zona donde debe ir la fecha (en el archivo HTML) lo siguiente:

```html
<tag>La fecha que queremos vvisualizar es:
  <script>
    document.write(convertirFecha(toString({{ $valorFecha }})));
  </script>
</tag>
```

Por otra parte haz una función en JavaScript que sea:

```js
function convertirFecha(fecha) {
  let year = fecha.split(" ")[2];
  let month = fecha.split(" ")[0]
    .toLocaleLowerCase()
    .replace("jan", "01")
    .replace("feb", "02")
    .replace("mar", "03")
    .replace("apr", "04")
    .replace("may", "05")
    .replace("jun", "06")
    .replace("jul", "07")
    .replace("aug", "08")
    .replace("sep", "09")
    .replace("oct", "10")
    .replace("nov", "11")
    .replace("dec", "12");
  let day = fecha.split(" ")[1];
  return year + "/" + day + "/" + month;
}
```

Lo he pasado todo a toLocaleLowerCase() para que te funcione si en vez de pasarte "jun" te pasa "Jun" o "JUN". Puede haber una forma de formateo más rápida pero espero que esta te sirva.

Te dejaré a continuación una prueba que he realizado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]